# Windows CE Web Application

Tags: asp.net, windows-ce

I have an ASP.NET app running on 2008 Server, application targetted for windows and runs on IF and FF browser, using itextsharp to create PDF forms and submit. 
Now a new requirment comes up and I have to generate a solution to run the app on Windows CE, or alternatively collect required data and sent to existing app on the server and create the form there. 
Any suggeted way of doing it? I am totally new to CE.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We know very little about your requirements at this point.  If it's a web app, have you tried running it from the web browser on the target Windows CE device to see if/how it runs?  If you're lucky, it might just work as-is, otherwise you may have to adjust your pages to handle the Windows CE browser specifically by agent.

Comment: Hello ctacke, I know it will not run on the CE device because of the pdf plug-in requirment , in fact I have tried on android browser and chrome with no luck, so for mobile devices, thought using a different type of form (web form instead of pdf) and somehow get the mobile app to talk to the server and produce a pdf form from the supplied data..